# Salesforce Validation in Docusign Custom Button

Tags: docusign

I have a Salesforce Docusign Custom Button in a custom object that I would like to add a simple validation. This will prevent the user from starting a new Docusign envelope if the validation is met. Using OnClick JavaScript this is what I have so far but I am getting an error message indicating

> "Invalid ID field: undefined".

If I add the validation after the `{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/DocuSign_JavaScript")}` then the button does nothing when clicked.

```
var payment = "Paid In Full";

var paymentstatus = '{!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Payment_Status__c}';

if (paymentstatus=payment) { 
    alert = ("Unable to process payment {!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Payment_Status__c}");
} 
else 
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

DST = '{!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.DocusignTemplate__c}'; 

CES = 'Team Florida - Request for Payment'; 

CEM = 'Request for payment of expense for {!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Campaign__c}'; 


window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
```

Comment: You do seem to have a logic issue on your if statement: *if (paymentstatus=payment) { * Should likely be == instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things odd with the code you've posted here. Let's run through it:

You're creating 2 variables: `payment` and `paymentstatus`. Both of these would technically be Strings. I'm guessing in your `if` statement you're trying to compare the two values, but using a single `=` you're trying to set `paymentstatus` to `payment`.

The first part should look like this, alls it will do is create a browser alert that will say:

> Unable to process payment Paid in full

```
if (paymentstatus == payment) { 
  alert = ("Unable to process payment {!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Payment_Status__c}");
}
```

Now your `else` statement is calling the file at `{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/DocuSign_JavaScript")}`. But that will only get called if the `paymentstatus` **is not** equal to `payment`. If `paymentstatus` is equal to `payment`. The code below your `if` `else` is still going to run and I'm guessing your variables `DST`, `CES` and `CEM` depend on that script being called? You don't appear to be creating them anywhere in the code you've provided.

The error could be a result of that.

Presumably you don't want anything to happen if the payment can't be processed? In which case you'd just want a little bit of formatting to your code by adding a few brackets. Something like below:

```
var payment = "Paid In Full";

var paymentstatus = '{!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Payment_Status__c}';

if (paymentstatus == payment) { 
  alert = ("Unable to process payment {!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Payment_Status__c}");
} 
else {
  {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

  DST = '{!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.DocusignTemplate__c}'; 

  CES = 'Team Florida - Request for Payment'; 

  CEM = 'Request for payment of expense for {!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Campaign__c}'; 


  window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
}
```

In other words, if `paymentstatus` is not equal to `payment`, execute the code within that `else` block. Otherwise you'd only be outputting that alert. Nothing else would happen.

I'd say this would be a good start, but it might not completely fix your problem!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The extra = fix the issue with the validation and it did create the docusign envelope if not = "Paid In Full" Unfortunately now if if does = "Paid In Full" when click it does nothing. The alert does not come up at all. I am declaring the DST, CES and CEM variable I had removed it. Here is the complete code as of now.

Comment: @MildredMorales good to know! Check the capitalisation and spelling of the `{!EFI_Event_Expenses__c.Payment_Status__c}` field. Make sure they totally match up. Also thinking about it in JS you don't need to do `alert = ("Abc123")`, it should just be `alert("Abc")`. You can use the Developer Console in most browsers (normally F12) to debug JavaScript. :)

Comment: It works!!! Basically all of the issues were indeed java related. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey Poet! Hope all is well. Wondering if you can help me out on a second if statement for this same code. If Grant Program equals "A" then use this Docusign Javascript else if Grant Program equal "B" then use this a different Docusign Javascript else error Grant Program not setup for payment.